# Pass the same value in structs in c

Tags: c

I have this code which is basically some logical gates and I want the user to give the input values and just the program to print the output.The problem is I wnat two gates to have the same inputs and so I want to give the same values to funcs_ptr[3]->in2 and
funcs_ptr[4]->in1.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef int (*CallBack)(int, int);
int myand (int a, int b);
int myor(int a, int b);
int mynand (int a, int b);
int mynor(int a, int b);
int myxor(int a, int b);
typedef struct gate
{
    CallBack f;
    struct gate * in1 ;
    struct gate * in2 ;
} Gate;

int getinput()
{
    int x;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    return x;
}

Gate * creategate(CallBack f)
{
    Gate * temp ;
    temp = malloc(sizeof (Gate));
    temp->f = f;
    temp->in1 = NULL;
    temp->in2 = NULL;
    return temp;
}

int eval(Gate *x)
{
    int a, b;
    if (x->in1 != NULL)
        a = eval(x->in1);
    if (x->in2 != NULL)
        b = eval(x->in2);
    if (x->in1==NULL && x->in2 == NULL)
        return (x->f)(0,0);
    else
        return (x->f)(a,b);
}
int main( )
{
    int i;
    CallBack funcs[] = {mynor, myand, myor, mynand, myxor};
    Gate * funcs_ptr[6  ], * inputs_ptr[6];
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        funcs_ptr[i] = creategate(funcs[i]);
    for(i=0;i<6;i++)
        inputs_ptr[i] = creategate(getinput);
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        funcs_ptr[i]->in1 = inputs_ptr[i];
        funcs_ptr[i]->in2 = inputs_ptr[i+1];
    }

    funcs_ptr[3] = creategate(funcs[3]);
    funcs_ptr[3]->in1 = funcs_ptr[0];
    /*--*/funcs_ptr[3]->in2 = funcs_ptr[1];

    funcs_ptr[4] = creategate(funcs[4]);
    /*--*/funcs_ptr[4]->in1 = funcs_ptr[1];
    funcs_ptr[4]->in2 = funcs_ptr[2];

    funcs_ptr[5] = creategate(funcs[3]);
    funcs_ptr[5]->in1 = funcs_ptr[3];
    funcs_ptr[5]->in2 = funcs_ptr[4];

    printf(">>>%d\n", eval(funcs_ptr[5]));
    return 0;
}


int myand (int a, int b)
{
    return a * b;
}

int myor(int a, int b)
{
    return a+b>0;
}

int mynand (int a, int b)
{
    return myand(a,b)==0;
}

int mynor(int a, int b)
{
    return myor(a,b)==0;
}

int myxor(int a, int b)
{
    if(a!=b) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

But when I run  the code the eval function calls getinput() two times instead of just passing the same value.
How can I pass the same value to both structs?

Comment: How is `creategate(getinput)` working? `getinput()` doesn't take the proper arguments for a `Callback`.

Comment: You need to define a way to represent constants in your gate network, not just functions.

Comment: If that was a typo and you meant `creategate(getinput())` then `getinput` still doesn't return a `CallBack`.

Comment: The Gate struct is part of the instructions so I can't change it and also most part of the code instead of main was part of the instructions so I have to use these functions.

Comment: I don't know about getinput but it works :)

Comment: `funcs_ptr[3] = creategate(funcs[3]);` and `funcs_ptr[4] = creategate(funcs[4]);` create memory leaks because you overwrite the pointer address previously allocated with `for (i = 0; i < nfuncs; i++) funcs_ptr[i] = creategate(funcs[i]);` Add `free (funcs_ptr[3]);` and `free (funcs_ptr[4]);` before calling and assigning `creategate()` to each again.