# Is there a way for the eval function to save the array a[4] after returning?

Tags: c

Im trying to make a program that represents a logic circuit and im having trouble having two gates share the same input. Using the function eval the inputs are stored in the array a[4] but when it returns, the array of the gate xor(c_ptr) is lost and then created again when called again but this time with its default values. Is there a way i can store the values and then reuse them after returning?(i cant change my aproach because of restrictions).Thank you in advance.(the gates use an array of ints to calculate the exit signal)

```
typedef int (*CallBack)(int a[]);
typedef struct gate
{
    char s[6];
    CallBack f;
    struct gate ** inputs ;
} Gate;

int myand(int a[4]);
int myor(int a[4]);
int mynand(int a[4]);
int mynor(int a[4]);
int myxor(int a[4]);

int getinput()
{
    int x;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    return x;
}
Gate * creategate(CallBack f,char w[])
{
    Gate * temp ;
    temp = malloc(sizeof (Gate));
    temp->f = f;
    strcpy(temp->s,w);
    temp->inputs = NULL;
    return temp;
}
int eval(Gate *x)
{
    int a[4]= {0,0,3,4};
    printf("%s\n",x->s);
    if(x->inputs!=NULL)
    {
        if(x->inputs[0]!=NULL)
        {
            a[0] = eval(x->inputs[0]);
            x->inputs[0]=NULL;
        }
        if(x->inputs[1]!=NULL)
        {
            a[1] = eval(x->inputs[1]);
            x->inputs[1]=NULL;
        }
        if(x->inputs[2]!=NULL)
        {
            a[2] = eval(x->inputs[2]);
            x->inputs[2]=NULL;
        }
    }
    if (x->inputs==NULL)
        return (x->f)(0);
    else
        return (x->f)(a);
}
int main( )
{
    Gate * a_ptr, * b_ptr, * c_ptr, * d_ptr, * e_ptr, * f_ptr, * g_ptr;

    a_ptr = creategate(myor,"OR1");
    b_ptr = creategate(mynand,"NAND2");
    c_ptr = creategate(myxor,"XOR2");
    d_ptr = creategate(mynor,"NOR3");
    e_ptr = creategate(myand,"AND3");
    f_ptr = creategate(myor,"OR3-1");
    g_ptr = creategate(myor,"OR3-2");

    a_ptr->inputs = malloc(3*sizeof(Gate *));
    a_ptr->inputs[0] = b_ptr;
    a_ptr->inputs[1] = c_ptr;
    a_ptr->inputs[2] = NULL;

    c_ptr->inputs = malloc(4*sizeof(Gate *));
    c_ptr->inputs[0] = e_ptr;
    c_ptr->inputs[1] = d_ptr;
    c_ptr->inputs[2] = g_ptr;
    c_ptr->inputs[3] = NULL;

    b_ptr->inputs = malloc(4*sizeof(Gate *));
    b_ptr->inputs[0] = c_ptr->inputs[1];
    b_ptr->inputs[1] = c_ptr->inputs[0];
    b_ptr->inputs[2] = f_ptr;
    b_ptr->inputs[3] = NULL;

    d_ptr->inputs = malloc(3*sizeof(Gate *));
    d_ptr->inputs[0] = creategate(getinput,"INPUT");
    d_ptr->inputs[1] = creategate(getinput,"INPUT");
    d_ptr->inputs[2] = NULL;

    e_ptr->inputs = malloc(3*sizeof(Gate *));
    e_ptr->inputs[0] = creategate(getinput,"INPUT");
    e_ptr->inputs[1] = creategate(getinput,"INPUT");
    e_ptr->inputs[2] = NULL;

    f_ptr->inputs = malloc(3*sizeof(Gate *));
    f_ptr->inputs[0] = creategate(getinput,"INPUT");
    f_ptr->inputs[1] = creategate(getinput,"INPUT");
    f_ptr->inputs[2] = NULL;

    g_ptr->inputs = malloc(3*sizeof(Gate *));
    g_ptr->inputs[0] = creategate(getinput,"INPUT");
    g_ptr->inputs[1] = creategate(getinput,"INPUT");
    g_ptr->inputs[2] = NULL;

    printf("%d", eval(a_ptr));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Make it a global variable instead of a local variable.

Comment: This looks very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72410497/pass-the-same-value-in-structs-in-c

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. @Barmar Sorry to disagree, but making something a global variable is usually not the best solution to a problem.

Comment: @Barmar no i just created my first account

Comment: How would saving the array solve the problem? As I told the other question, you need to design a way to represent stored values in your inputs.

Comment: @Barman if i saved the inputs for each instance of eval, i could use the already calculated inputs for a gate that shares an input with another gate, that already calculated and used those very inputs. Sorry if im being all over the place but ive been on this for days

Comment: If a gate is an input for many other gates, your program will call `eval` for that gate (and its inputs, and inputs of its inputs...) many times. Is this what you want to avoid?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. m. it will call eval and store the inputs values in the array for all the gates that share them, but when the eval of one of those gates returns , it will lose the inputs values from its array and if it gets called again, the array will be filled with the default numbers, which will give the gate the wrong inputs thus a wrong output. I want to be able to save the values even after the eval returns so if it gets called later on, it will have the same values stored

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. There is no state in the system, so how could the same gate possibly get evaluated with different inputs? Please post a [mcve], the output you want/expect, and the output it actually produces.